# Negation Symbol over character in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, characters

Is there any way to achieve a negation symbol over a character within an excel cell ? Im looking for sth. what you can do in latex easily with

```
\neg
```

or

```
\Overline
```

Comment: Pick a **font** that supports that typography.

Comment: Thanks a lot, didn't know that looking for another font would do it.

Comment: Another question: Now using [LogicRQ](http://www.roman-eisele.de/typo/pages/logicrq.html) as font. But this only supports the traditional negation signs. Do you maybe know a font, which supports the overline negation, preferably which i can apply over more than one character ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very short macro that places an **X** with an overbar in the active cell:

```
Sub XBar()
   ActiveCell.Font.Name = "Arial MS Unicode"
   ActiveCell.Value = "X" & ChrW(773)
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Char 172 gives the negation symbol ¬

Comment: @Raystafarian You are correct!